# Extract return value from FOR loop

Tags: java, for-loop, return-value

I am trying to implement a method whose return value is defined into the for loop. However I always get eclipse telling me that I have to initialize it. But if I do this, and set it to say, null, it always stays null... What am I doing wrong?

```
public String getPoints(String team){
    String teamName;
    String outcome;
    for ( FootballClub club : league )
    {
        teamName = club.getName();
        if ( teamName.trim().toLowerCase().equals( team ) )
        {
            outcome = ( team + "  " + club.getPoints() ) + " Points";
        }
    }
    return outcome;
}
```

Comment: An answer has already been given, but you could do `return (team+"  " +club.getPoints())+ " Points";` in side the for-loop and `return null;` at the end of the method and maybe move `String teamName` inside the for-loop. 1) you will exit the for loop right away instead of checking all other clubs as well even if the match was already found 2) You don't need an `outcome` variable

Comment: You are setting `outcome` only if some condition is met (the correct team-name) - probably there is no club with that team-name in your collection.

Comment: *But if I do this, and set it to say, null, it always stays null...* This may be because of your team is not matched with league object. Initialize outcome to null and concentrate on for loop logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this, get rid of extra variables, of course if there will be no more operations with  `outcome`:

```
public String getPoints(String team){
    String teamName;
    for ( FootballClub club : league )
    {
        teamName = club.getName();
        if ( teamName.trim().toLowerCase().equals( team ) )
        {
            return ( team + "  " + club.getPoints() ) + " Points";
        }
    }
    return "null or some string if .equals( team ) false for all clubs";
}
```

Comment: Could as well return `null` at the end. Or throw an exception. Would prefer `null` though.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since the `league` Collection/array (whatever it is) you are iterating over may be empty, `outcome` may not be initialized (since the body of the loop will never be entered in this case).

Just give it an initial value :

```
String outcome = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

As **Local variables** are not given default initial values. They must be initialized explicitly before they are used which is why your innocent **Eclipse** is doing his duty to inform you about the compilation Error .

Initialize **outcome** with null , it will not always be null , If team for which you are calling getPoints() present in **league collection** then your outcome will definately change .

```
public String getPoints(String team){
    String teamName;
    String outcome=null; // Initialization is must
    for ( FootballClub club : league )
    {
        teamName = club.getName();
        if ( teamName.trim().toLowerCase().equals( team ) )
        {
            outcome = ( team + "  " + club.getPoints() ) + " Points";
        }
    }
    return outcome;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `break`:

```
if ( teamName.trim().toLowerCase().equals( team ) )
{
     outcome = ( team + "  " + club.getPoints() ) + " Points";          
     break;
}
```

And when you're expecting to `outcome` value, you will need to:
`if (outcome != null)`

Comment: Maybe you assume that one would already have read the other answers when reading yours, but for the sake of completeness, would you mind adding that `outcome` must be initialized with `null` first?

Comment: When is defined as: `String outcome;`  it means that `outcome = null`

Comment: As @NeerajJain pointed out, *Local variables are not given default initial values*. So, __no__, you should initialize `outcome`.